# How does Python import packages and files with the same name?

Tags: python, django, python-import

I have a Django project and the directory is as follows.[image]

There are a Python file named `permissions.py` and a module name `permissions`.I want to import `permissions.helpers` but it raises `ImportError` and the error message is `cannot import name helpers`.

The first element in `sys.path` is the project directory(the parent directory of `myapp`) as I expected.I thought Python Interpreter should try to find modules or files from `sys.path` but it seems to search in the current module first.Am i wrong and how can i import `permissions.helpers` without using `absolute_import`?

Comment: can you try with Relative import like `from .permissions import helpers`?

Comment: Which module are you trying to use either `permissions` into? `from .persmissions import helper` or `from ..permissions import helpers` depending what is trying to use should work I think.

Comment: Actually `from ..permissions import helpers`.I tried but it raise `ValueError: Attempted relative import beyond toplevel package`.

Comment: Check if this helps you out... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder